# Inserting a values to DB takes too long

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm receiving a data from `upload form` to `views.py` in Django and I'm saving it to a DB (MongoDB). But the data are too big, so it takes a lot of time and CPU. I found why it takes so long, but I'm not able to send this data by other means...
this is my code

```py
csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]
file_type = request.POST.get("type", "")
file_data = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")
    if file_type == "val3":
        lines = file_data.split("\n")
        items = []
        item = ""
        for line in lines:
            column = line.split(',')
            try:
                item = kokyaku(        # HERE I'm calling `kokyaku` model every time
                顧客CD = int(column[0]),
                顧客補助CD = int(column[1]),
                顧客名称s=str(column[2]),
                顧客名称=str(column[3]),
                顧客名称カナ=str(column[4]),
                法人名称=str(column[5]),
                代表者名称=str(column[6]),
                住所=str(column[7]),
                電話番号=str(int(column[8])),
                地区名称=str(column[9]),
                データマッチ用電話番号=int(column[10]),
                契約状態=str(column[11])
                )
                items.append(item)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        kokyaku.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

I'm calling `kokyaku` model every time in loop, so its extremely slow... I tried to send it as `list` of `dicts` like this

```
    item = {      
             "顧客CD" : int(column[0]),
             .....
            }
items.append(item)
```

so I could avoid calling `kokyaku` every time - it maked process faster, but my model is not able to receive data in this format... What could I do? If possible I would like to use `bulk_create` to make it faster...
Here is my models.py

```py
class kokyaku(models.Model):
    顧客CD = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    顧客補助CD = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    顧客名称s = models.TextField(blank=True)
    顧客名称 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    顧客名称カナ = models.TextField(blank=True)
    法人名称 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    代表者名称 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    住所 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    地区名称 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    電話番号 = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    データマッチ用電話番号 = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    契約状態 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        string = str(self.顧客CD) + " - " + self.顧客名称
        return string
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to instead on inserting one by one inside a for loop , you can create a list of items from your csv file and insert all of them at once

Comment: thanks for the answer, as "list of items" do you mean `list of values`(strings)? Because I have a n row with n columns I can't figure, how could I split this values for every row (there are possible empty columns)

Comment: yes sure , i guess you might extract list items from your csv file first and insert a batch of them into related table instead of inserting one by one, it takes a lot of operation to handle, and inserting one by one would absolutely take a lot of time instead of inserting for example 100 of them at once

Comment: I'm not sure how could I rewrite this part `item = kokyaku(顧客CD = int(column[0]),...` To accept a list of values

Comment: what DB you are using? imguessing you are using SQL kind one , right ?

Comment: I'm using a MongoDB

Comment: its so much easy though, you can use `insert_many` on your related collection and pass a list of items that you extracted!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, could you please provide me a `insert_many` example, how could I resolve it? I have never used it before, and not sure how it works

Comment: its so easy you just type the name of collection like `Collection.insert_many([ ... ])`

Comment: I found this `db.collection.insertMany()` but its an syntax for Mongo DB not Python